# Выдаёт ошибку при использовании при использовании strcpy

Tags: c++, строки, указатели, const

Есть вот такое задание:

```
//Задание 6.Конструктор + деструктор = функциональное
    // замыкание. Класс MyString
    // Посредством конструктора (конструкторов) и деструктора обеспечьте
    //корректные инициализацию и деактивацию объекта
    //C помощью остановов определите когда происходит
    //захват и освобождение памяти для строки-члена класса

    cout << "Задание 6 \n" << endl;
    {
        MyString  str1("It's my string1!");
        //Создайте метод GetString(), который обеспечит доступ к хранящейся строке.
        //С помощью cout и метода GetString() распечатайте строку объекта str1
        //Замечание: подумайте, как следует корректно реализовать метод GetString().

        //Подсказка 1:
        //приведенный ниже код должен работать:
        std::cout<<str1.GetString()<<std::endl;

        //Подсказка 2:
        //приведенный ниже код НЕ должен работать:
        //str1.GetString()[1] = 'W';

        //Подсказка 3:
        //приведенный ниже код должен работать:
        const MyString  str2("It's my string2!");
        std::cout<<str2.GetString()<<std::endl;
    }
    stop
```

Объявил класс

```
class MyString
{
    char* m_pStr;   //строка-член класса
   
public:

    MyString(); // конструктор без параметров
    MyString(const char* str);// конструктор с параметром
    MyString(const MyString& other); // конструктор копирования
    ~MyString(); // деструктор

    const char* GetString();
};

// Определение конструктора.

MyString::MyString() // конструктор без параметров
{
   m_pStr = nullptr;
  
}

MyString::MyString(const char* str)// конструктор с параметрами
{
    m_pStr = const_cast<char*>(str);
    /*m_pStr = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
    strcpy(m_pStr, str);*/
}

//MyString::MyString(const MyString& other) // копирующий конструктор 
//{
//  int size = strlen(other.m_pStr);
//  this->m_pStr = new char[size + 1];
//  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
//  {
//      this->m_pStr[i] = other.m_pStr[i];
//  }
//  this->m_pStr[size] = '\0';
//}

// Определение деструктора.

MyString::~MyString()// деструктор
{
    //delete[] m_pStr;
}

const char* MyString::GetString()
{
    return m_pStr;
}
```

ВЫдаёт две ошибки:

Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  C4996   'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.   1   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Обучение\С++\Лекции по С++\DEV-200\Практика\Lab 1\myString.cpp    18

Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления    Подробное описание
Ошибка (активно)    E1086   Объект содержит квалификаторы типа, несовместимые с элементом функцию "MyString::GetString".    1   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Обучение\С++\Лекции по С++\DEV-200\Практика\Lab 1\main.cpp    252                 тип объекта: const MyString

Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  C2662   const char *MyString::GetString(void): невозможно преобразовать указатель "this" из "const MyString" в "MyString &" 1   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Обучение\С++\Лекции по С++\DEV-200\Практика\Lab 1\main.cpp    252

Подскажите: почему ругается strcpy и как корректно получить значение переменной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вопрос — о `strcpy`. Он не ругается, а предупреждает, что безопаснее использовать `strcpy_s`. Но у вас использование верное, с выделенным достаточным количеством памяти, так что можете просто написать первой строкой

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Больше ругаться не будет.

Второй вопрос — вы объявили константный объект

```
const MyString  str2
```

а функцию-член вызываете неконстантную. Или исправьте на

```
MyString  str2
```

или объявление исправьте как

```
const char* GetString() const;
```

ну и, соответственно, реализацию...

```
const char* MyString::GetString() const
```

P.S. Но вообще у вас с константностью наверчено, гм, лишнего...

```
m_pStr = const_cast<char*>(str);
```

Очень неприятный момент. Потому что вы так в результате вроде как можете менять константную строку, в том числе литерал, что чревато...

Comment: Да, Я это знаю. Поэтому пытаюсь сделать через m_pStr = new char[strlen(str) + 1];

Comment: Со вторым вопросом всё получилось. Огромное спасибо!!! С первым не выходит. Выдаёт ту же ошибку.

Comment: Вы где строку разместили? Надо **самой первой** строкой. До `#include`ов

Comment: Да. Всё отлично работает. Это я невнимательный. Поместил после #includeов .Спасибо огромное!!!!! ))))))

Comment: Ёщё раз спасибо!!!)))